# Fastest way to get certain lines from text file

Tags: c#, arrays

I have some text files that have a certain structure. At the start of each row I have some word for example "true" or "false". Something like this:

```
$True 3 5 1 8
$False 12 5 a z
$False 1,5,7 
$True 123
$True 7ao
$False 198
```

I need to get an array, list or something like that with values:

```
$False 12 5 a z
$False 1,5,7 
$False 198
```

The number of rows is not known, I am trying to find the fastest way to read only rows with a certain start word (False).
I tried to parse using the `string.Split` method, and then adding to list `if word == word`, but problem is in speed, if I have 5-6000 lines this becomes slow. Are there faster way for something like this?

Comment: It would help if you could show us your code so far. Maybe your concept is correct, just the execution may need improvement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be fast enough:

```
var filteredLines = 
        File.ReadLines("path")
            .Where(line => line.StartsWith(word))
            .ToList()
```

becase [`ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) iterates through file line by line, not loading whole into memory (from MSDN):

> The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(yourFilePath))
{
  string line;
  while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    if (line.StartsWith("$False"))
       list.Add(line);
  }
}
// do something with your result list
```

If you are using `ReadAllLines()`, this is likely to cause your performance issues as the full file is internally returned as a string array, on which splitting will be an expensive operation. The solution above alleviates this.

Comment: better still would be to feed the filtered results into a memorystream then you could process each line as it is read from the file in a parallel manner, see Patterns for parallel programming by Stephen Toub, Section on decortaor to pipeline in Pipelines section is excellent and tackles this exact problem. http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/vihavain/k13/sem/items/Patterns_of_Parallel_Programming_CSharp.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I assume you try to read the lines with ReadLine method of StreamReader.

So I would suggest instead of using ReadLine method, read byte by byte from start to end, so that you would know if the line starts with the keyword which you look for or not.

To achieve this I always use FileStream, go for something like below to find the end of line characters. So you can add some if conditions after sb.Insert(0, value); line

```
fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

for (long offset = 0; offset < fs.Length; offset++)
{
    char value = (char)((byte)fs.ReadByte());

    if (value == 0xA)//  hex \n
    {
         if (offset == fs.Length)
             continue;
    }
    else if (value == 0xD)// hex \r
    {
         if (offset == fs.Length - 1)
             continue;
    }
    sb.Insert(0, value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
var neededLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Path\To\file.txt")
                                .Where(x => x.StartsWith("False"));
```

1. Read all lines from the file
2. Take those that start with 'False'

**Update**

To oppose those ridiculous comments about performance:

I tested a similar file like the OPs with **25200** lines and this finished in **11ms**. And that time even includes a call to `Count()` on the result (which is 12600). Otherwise it was **3ms**. I don't think performance is an issue here!

Comment: -1 What about the performance concern? OP already knows how to read the file and filter out the lines.

Comment: @rae1 is downvoting every answer here

Comment: @Neel I'm not down voting every answer; only two which happen to be the same answer in terms of code and no explanation as to why or if they actually perform fast enough. Wim Hollebrandse's answer actually tries to address the OP. Reading the entire file and then filtering but lines is easy but *hardly* efficient or performant, especially with big files.

Comment: `ReadAllLines` can be inefficient for big files. It is also unnecessary in this case.

Comment: For 5k or 6k lines ReadAllLines is probably efficient enough. Could even be _more_ efficient to read all file at once.